# "invalid argument" when trying to access to network from nautilus

Tags: networking, server, nautilus, samba

I was reading this could be a kind of bug. So, I have 2 samba file servers, mint-satellite and ubuntu-andres. I can't reach when I double click, I can't reach when I write in Go To: `smb://ubuntu-andres` but I can reach when I write `smb://ubuntu-andres/share`.
The other server has the same config and it runs correctly, every machine can reach it.
Heres my smb.conf from servers:

```
    [share]
Comment = shared folder
Path = /share
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
Public = yes
Guest ok = yes
```

[image]

Edit: This could be a hint, those are repeated, but I don't remember what did I do or what service I started, this is a screenshot of ubuntu-andres (the file server with the problem):

[image]

Edit3: The problem seems to be with linux machines, all of windows machines I can reach when I put `\\ubuntu-andres`.

Comment: Do Ubuntu-Andres and Mint-Satellite both have static IP addresses?

Comment: No, dhcp, but its really necesary? I haven't problems to reach the other file server with dhcp.

Comment: Never said it was necessary. Was asking the question so that irrelevant configuration details can be excluded from the answer 

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think its a bug, "The Invalid argument error is brought to you by the good people at Gnome High Command when they created a bug in gvfsd-smb-browse. The client is attempting to access a server with the SMB1 dialect of samba when no such dialect exits on the server." https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=333753&start=20

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, adding WS-Discovery will solve this problem.  See this bug report for more info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1831441.
Here is a possible solution, from that report:

> Windows 10 disables the smbv1 client dialect on new builds and this in
> turn disables NetBIOS host discovery in its File manager. Configured
> this way Win10 will never be able to browse the network and discover a
> Linux Samba server. With the addition of WSD in Ubuntu Win10 will
> discover the Linux Samba server using its native WSD protocol.
>
> There exists in github something that has most of this already
> created. One can use it in Ubuntu but it requires some work to
> implement:
>
> [1] Download the file:
>
> wget https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/archive/master.zip
>
> [2] After unzipping it rename the python script:
>
> sudo mv wsdd-master/src/wsdd.py wsdd-master/src/wsdd
>
> [3] Copy it to /usr/bin
>
> sudo cp wsdd-master/src/wsdd /usr/bin
>
> [4] A systemd service file is already provided in the package it just
> needs to be copied to the correct location:
>
> sudo cp wsdd-master/etc/systemd/wsdd.service /etc/systemd/system
>
> [5] The wsdd.service file has to be edited to remove references to the
> nobody user:
>
> #User=nobody
> #Group=nobody
>
> [6] Then enable the service:
>
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload sudo systemctl start wsdd sudo systemctl
> enable wsdd